# How to verify that the connection in PDO is secured with SSL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ssl, pdo

**Hello**,
I recently installed an SSL certificate associated with my database to secure data transfers between my database and my web server. For information, I use MysqlServer (like BDD) and PDO on my web server to make requests.

I followed these orders to install an SSL certificate at MysqlServer:

```
sudo mysql_ssl_rsa_setup --uid=mysql
```

I also enabled this option to secure all exchanges (require_secure_transport = ON).
So the installation worked very well on the Mysql server side.

Now, when I want to connect to my database via PDO from my web server I use this:

```
<?php

//Connexion à la base de données.
 $options = array(
 PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
 PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 BLABLABLA
 -----END CERTIFICATE-----
",
 PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 BLABLABLA
 -----END CERTIFICATE-----
 ",
 PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
 BLABLABLA
 -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
 ",
 PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,);
 try
 {   
     $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=***;dbname=***;charset=utf8', '***', '***', $options);
 }
 catch(Exception $e)
 {
     echo "Problème de connexion à la base de données. Réessayez !";
     exit();
 }
 ?>
```

Here too everything works, but I would like to make sure that the connections are encrypted.
So from PDO, I executed the following command: SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE "Ssl_cipher";
and I get this: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA. So everything is fine. However, as soon as I change my certificate (delete a few letters and numbers for example), the connection is always "secure". The same applies when I indicate an incorrect location of the certificates. So I have the impression that even without the certificates the PDO connection is still secure.
Can you clarify that for me?

**Thanks you ;)**

Comment: Maybe not use `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I followed the tutorial that says: "The PDO option MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT is important to disable checking of the server certificate. If omitted, you'll receive an error: `SQLSTATE[HY000][2002]`.".

Comment: You talking about [this site](https://www.saotn.org/how-to-use-ssl-in-php-data-objects-pdo-mysql/)? It looks like it's only required if you're running MySQL on Windows Server, is that what you're doing?

Comment: No, my server is on Linux.  In short, I have this setting active at database server configuration: require_secure_transport = ON.  So, in any case, if the connection works, it means that the connection is necessarily encrypted?  Thanks to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently in the latest versions of Mysql, encryption of data in transit is done without a certificate (on the client side). In any case, they do not need to be specified with PDO. Why? Mysql acts like an HTTPS site (when you log in to a site, you don't need to have certificates already present on your computer). So we can do things like this:

```
$options = [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => true,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
];
...
```

Comment: In PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA, you need to set the file path of pem format that contains list of CA.So,it's string, not boolean.